# Get localized name of each day over next seven days using Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I should make this calendar of the week with different types of orders to be shown numerically depending on the data I receive. Do you have any idea how I could do this? for java code i should  use material or native libraries

https://i.ibb.co/LvbgW4T/Immagine-2022-03-28-090511.jpg

Comment: Your Question is unclear. Rewrite to ask a narrow question on a specific technical issue. And, explain how have existing Questions and Answers have not addressed your issue. There are many existing pages on managing content by day of week. Tip: [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)

Comment: You're right, looking at the image I used the grid layout to insert the names of the week. I need to dynamically show the days of the week in the gridlayout. For example, today is Tuesday and it will be Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon. Tomorrow in the same gridlayout it will have to go out Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue.

Comment: (A) So your question is how to list the next seven days of the week, localized? (B) Edit the body of your Question to post details, rather than post Comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Example code, not for production use.

```
LocalDate
.now()
.datesUntil( LocalDate.now().plusWeeks( 1 ) )
.map( localDate -> localDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.TAIWAN ) 
.toList()
```

(In real work, never call `now` twice. At the end of the day, you may get two different values.)

## Details

Per [your Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71643589/calendar-of-week-with-order-count-android-studio/71661861#comment126642622_71643589), you are asking how to list the next seven days of the week, localized.

Capture the current date. This requires a time zone, as the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Loop seven days, incrementing the date. Interrogate each date for its day-of-week. Get the localized name of that day.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
for( int index = 0 ; index < 7 ; index ++ ) 
{
    LocalDate ld = today.plusDays( index ) ;
    DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
    String dowName = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , locale ) ;
    System.out.println ( dowName ) ;
}
```

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: "at the end of the day" – Nice wordplay!